# SQL why input string becomes 0?

Tags: python, sql, psycopg2

I'm using python's psycopg2 to create a table and the insert SQL string look like this

```
create_table ='''CREATE TABLE Datetime_Response(
   rid BIGINT NOT NULL,
   qid BIGINT,
   roid BIGINT,
   rotext VARCHAR(20)
)'''

INSERT INTO Datetime_Response (rid, qid, roid, rotext)
VALUES
 (13020638659, 711799502, 4681912759, 07/21/2021)
```

But the output is weird. All the datetime string becomes `0`. I tried both `VARCHAR` and `TEST` in the column `rotext`. They all show `0`. I don't know what goes wrong.

```
(13020638659, 711799502, 4681912759, '0')
```

This is what the `values` looks like

```
values = list(entry.values())
        print(values)
['13020638659', '711799502', '4681912759', '07/21/2021']
```

And this is what the insert syntax look like

```
values_str = "(%s)" % (', '.join( values ))
sql_string = "INSERT INTO %s (%s)\nVALUES\n %s" % (
            table_name,
            ', '.join(columns),
            values_str
        )
        print(sql_string)
INSERT INTO GZ_Datetime_Response (rid, qid, roid, rotext)
VALUES
 (13020638659, 711799502, 4681912759, 07/21/2021)
```

Comment: Because 7 divided by 21 divided by 2021 equals 0.  If you want a string, then you have to enclose it in quotes: `'07/21/2021'`.  You haven't shown us your real code, so we can't show how to let the database connector do the substitution, which you should ALWAYS do.

Comment: Use proper date data type to store dates.

Comment: @Tim Roberts Sorry, I didn't provide enough information. But I believe the datetime is already in quotes.

Comment: You are not adding quotes when you build your string, and you can see that it's not in quotes in the INSERT statement you show above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because 7 divided by 21 divided by 2021 is close to zero. `/` is integer division in Python 2 if both operands are an integer. Quote your value: `07/21/2021`

**Your query is open to SQL injection attacks by malicious users of your script!**

```py
values = list(entry.values())
        print(values)
['13020638659', '711799502', '4681912759', '07/21/2021']
values_str = "(%s)" % (', '.join( values ))
sql_string = "INSERT INTO %s (%s)\nVALUES\n %s" % (
            table_name,
            ', '.join(columns),
            values_str
        )
        print(sql_string)
```

When using your string values to format your string, you will end up with:

> INSERT INTO GZ_Datetime_Response (rid, qid, roid, rotext)
> VALUES (13020638659, 711799502, 4681912759, 07/21/2021)

which does not contain any quotation marks. *Use prepared statements* to avoid problems caused by wrong types and to stop hackers from misusing your application/database.

If, for whatever reason, you cannot use prepared statements, make sure the string ends up as string in your final statement:

1. `values = ['13020638659', '711799502', '4681912759', "'07/21/2021'"]`
2. or `INSERT INTO GZ_Datetime_Response (rid, qid, roid, rotext) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, '%s)`

Answer (score 1):

Do it like this.  Let the connector fill in the properly quoted values:

```
sql_string = "INSERT INTO %s (%s)\nVALUES (%s)" % (
            table_name,
            ','.join(columns),
            ','.join(['?']*len(values))
        )
cur.execute( sql_string, values )
```

Comment: That looks cool. But `'?'` doesn't work. I have to change it to `'%s'`

Comment: That depends on which database you are using.  I should have said that.